# proper way to present a cardScrollActivity before a live card for google glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

What is the proper way to present a card scroll activity before presenting a service?  For example, if I wanted to allow the user to select a song in a scroll view before playing the song in a live card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case I would still have the service be the entry point and use the following to start the scroll activity from the service (depending on the use case);

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CardScrollActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

Then after making your selection and before finishing your activity, using a service interface method publish your live card from the service or use a broadcast receiver to notify the service to publish.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any reason why I would not want to publish the live card and then create the intent? -- since after the activity finishes control returns to the service anyway.

Comment: depends how you manage "control" it could just be event driven rather than a loop (due to battery)